# Unable to parse Json back into a table in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing

I have generated a Json document using `FOR JSON PATH` in SQL Server, however, when I try to parse it back into a table, I just get `NULL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON('{"Customer":[{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11060,"UnitPrice":45.6000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11061,"UnitPrice":18.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":21,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11062,"UnitPrice":12.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11187,"UnitPrice":43.9000,"ProductsOnOrder":20,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11217,"UnitPrice":10.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":6,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11218,"UnitPrice":18.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11554,"UnitPrice":55.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11555,"UnitPrice":13.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11846,"UnitPrice":25.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":16,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11847,"UnitPrice":45.6000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11992,"UnitPrice":13.2500,"ProductsOnOrder":40,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11993,"UnitPrice":21.5000,"ProductsOnOrder":20,"ShipCity":"Berlin"}]}')
WITH
(
    CustomerID NVARCHAR(255) '$.Customer'
)
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? `Customer` is a top level property, and definitely doesn't match `CustomerID`. If you *removed* the `WITH` clause you'd see that the string is parsed. `Customer`'s value is an array though

Comment: I need to convert it to a flat scrtucture. Column names should be, CustomerID, CustomerName, etc. Here is the code that generated the document that I am trying to convert back to a table: SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerNumber, C.Customer, C.City, O.OrderID, O.UnitPrice, O.ProductsOnOrder, O.ShipCity
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
WHERE CustomerNumber LIKE 'ALFKI'
 FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Customer')

Comment: You need to specify a JSON Path expression in `OPENJSON` that selects the data you want. WITH applies to the result of the JSON Path expression. Without it, the root object is parsed and one line returned per attribute. In this case, it's `Customer` with an array of values. If you use `$.Customer` in `OPENJSON` though, WITH will be applied to the documents *inside* the array pointed to by `$.Customer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a JSON Path expression in `OPENJSON` that selects the data you want. 
WITH applies to the result of the JSON Path expression.

Without it, the root object is parsed and one line returned per attribute. In this case, it's `Customer` with an array of values. If you used `OPENJSON` without a path, you'd get :

```
key       value              type
Customer  [{"Customer".....  4
```

If the root object contained another property, eg `"moo":123` it would be returned in another line :

```
key       value              type
Customer  [{"Customer".....  4
moo       123                2
```

To select the contents of the `Customer` property, you need to use the `$.Customer` path. This will return the array items :

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.Customer')

Results
-------

0   {"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerN  5
1   {"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerN  5
```

WITH now applies to the array items and :

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.Customer')
WITH(
    CustomerID NVARCHAR(255) '$.CustomerID',
    CustomerNumber NVARCHAR(255) '$.CustomerNumber',
    Customer NVARCHAR(255) '$.Customer'
)
```

Will return

```
CustomerID  CustomerNumber  Customer
10021       ALFKI           Alfreds Futterkiste
10021       ALFKI           Alfreds Futterkiste
10021       ALFKI           Alfreds Futterkiste
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"Customer":[{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11060,"UnitPrice":45.6000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11061,"UnitPrice":18.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":21,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11062,"UnitPrice":12.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11187,"UnitPrice":43.9000,"ProductsOnOrder":20,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11217,"UnitPrice":10.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":6,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11218,"UnitPrice":18.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11554,"UnitPrice":55.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":15,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11555,"UnitPrice":13.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11846,"UnitPrice":25.0000,"ProductsOnOrder":16,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11847,"UnitPrice":45.6000,"ProductsOnOrder":2,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11992,"UnitPrice":13.2500,"ProductsOnOrder":40,"ShipCity":"Berlin"},{"CustomerID":10021,"CustomerNumber":"ALFKI","Customer":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","OrderID":11993,"UnitPrice":21.5000,"ProductsOnOrder":20,"ShipCity":"Berlin"}]}'


SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.Customer') 
      WITH
      (
        CustomerID NVARCHAR(255) '$.CustomerID'
      )
```